# Moving a div from below another to above upon window resize

Tags: html, razor

I have two divs, A and B. B is under A. Would it be possible to put it above A instead when I resize the window vertically narrow enough? Can this be emulated by hiding/showing divs based on size?

Comment: why would you do that? What is your scenario?

Comment: @Robert Not my desire so I don't know the reasoning, but the scenario is that a mobile view (the narrowed window size) would have these elements switched.

Comment: You can use a media query that changes the positioning based on the size of the window.

Comment: exactly, this is done with media queries, actually you could look at responsive design practices

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're talking about is broadly known as [responsive design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design).

Sample code which demonstrates possible solution for your problem is shown below. It uses `resize` event on the `window` element, and then hides chosen element, based on the actual window width. The `redesign` method finally should contain any appropriate logic, which designs the view accordingly to its actual width:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    redesign();
    $(window).resize(function(){
        redesign();
    });
});

function redesign(){
    if ($(window).width() < 640) {
        $("#divA").hide();
    }else{
        $("#divA").show();
    }
}
```

Look at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KB2pq/) sample (obviously resize the window to see some results). If you're interested in moving DOM elements in relationship to each other, check jquery [insertBefore](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/) method.